# Angular observable data not loading on component init

Tags: angular

I have a data service that I use to load data in a component like this:

```
this.dataService.getUserData().subscribe(user => {
    this.user = user;
});
```

Now when ever data is `pushed/set` (like this `this.dataService.setUser(user);`), it updates the data in component fine!

But if my component hides for some reason and then shows again, the component is initialized again and the service is also subscribed successfully on init, but the current data is not loaded to my component's `user` object until the next push/set is called on the data service.

Is there some way that on init, not only the service is subscribed but also the current data from the data service is loaded?

Comment: One method I think is that I have a `getUserDataInit()` function in the service which returns the data directly without Observable. But is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md)

Here's how you can create a service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private userData = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({}); //user proper datatype and format initially for userdata
    userDataInfo = this.userData.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    changeUserData(userData: any) {
        this.userData.next(userData);
    }
}
```

Wherever you're getting the user data you can call this service like this

```
this.dataServcie.changeUserData(userData);
```

And when you need this data again, just call

```
this.data.tokenInfo.subscribe(userData => {
  if(userData) this.userData = userData;
});
```

That's it, No need for both components to be child parent or even in any relationship, this is by far the best way to share data between components in angular.

Comment: Only changing `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject` made it all work like required. Thank you.

Comment: Hey.. this worked, but now the down stream component doesnt respond to changes in the var. Only accepts initial value .. what to do?